# Sou iniciante e gostaria de saber o que está errado no meu código

Tags: python

```
from random import randint
computador = randint(1, 5)
print('\033[31m=\033[m'*30)
print('        \033[30mMENU DE JOGO\033[m')
print('\033[31m=\033[m'*30)
print('PEDRA, PAPEL, TESOURA, LAGARTO, SPOCK')
print('''opções:
[ 0 ] Regras
[ 7 ] Jogar
[ 6 ] Sair''')
n = int(input('Qual a sua opção:'))
while True:
    if n < 0 or n > 7:
        print('\033[31mOPÇÃO INVÁLIDA\033[m')
    elif n == 0:
        print('''Manual de como jogar pedra papel tesoura lagarto Spock:
Tesoura corta papel
papel cobre a pedra
pedra esmaga o lagarto 
Lagarto envenena Spock
Spock quebra a tesoura
tesoura decapita o lagarto
lagarto come o papel
papel refuta Spock
Spock vaporiza a pedra
pedra esmaga a tesoura'''.upper())
        print('PEDRA, PAPEL, TESOURA, LAGARTO, SPOCK')
        print('''opções:
        [ 0 ] Regras
        [ 7 ] Jogar
        [ 6 ] Sair''')
        n = int(input('Qual a sua opção:'))
    if n == 0:
            print('''
Manual de como jogar pedra papel tesoura lagarto Spock:
Tesoura corta papel
papel cobre a pedra
pedra esmaga o lagarto 
Lagarto envenena Spock
Spock quebra a tesoura
tesoura decapita o lagarto
lagarto come o papel
papel refuta Spock
Spock vaporiza a pedra
pedra esmaga a tesoura'''.upper())
    if n == 6:
        break
    if n > 7 or n < 0:
        print('\033[31mOPÇÃO INVÁLIDA\033[m')
        n = int(input('Qual a sua opção:'))
    if n == 7:
        while True:
            print('''
[ 1 ] Pedra
[ 2 ] Papel
[ 3 ] Tesoura
[ 4 ] Lagarto
[ 5 ] Spock
[ 6 ] Voltar''')
            n = int(input('Qual a sua opção:'))
            if n == 6:
                print('\033[31m=\033[m' * 30)
                print('        \033[30mMENU DE JOGO\033[m')
                print('\033[31m=\033[m' * 30)
                print('''
PEDRA, PAPEL, TESOURA, LAGARTO, SPOCK''')
                print('''
opções:
[ 0 ] Regras
[ 7 ] Jogar
[ 6 ] Sair''')
                n = int(input('Qual a sua opção:'))
                if n == 6:
                    break
                if n > 7 or n < 0:
                    print('\033[31mOPÇÃO INVÁLIDA\033[m')
            if computador == 1:
                if n == 1:
                    print('\033[33mEMPATE\033[m')
                    print('-=' * 10)
                    print('computador =', computador)
                    print('Jogador =', n)
                    print('-=' * 10)
                if n == 2:
                    print('\033[34mJogador Vence!\033[m')
                    print('-=' * 10)
                    print('computador =', computador)
                    print('Jogador =', n)
                    print('-=' * 10)
                if n == 3:
                    print('\033[32mComputador Vence!\033[m')
                    print('-=' * 10)
                    print('computador =', computador)
                    print('Jogador =', n)
                    print('-=' * 10)
                if n == 4:
                    print('\033[32mComputador Vence!\033[m')
                    print('-=' * 10)
                    print('computador =', computador)
                    print('Jogador =', n)
                    print('-=' * 10)
                if n == 5:
                    print('\033[34mJogador Vence!\033[m')
                    print('-=' * 10)
                    print('computador =', computador)
                    print('Jogador =', n)
                    print('-=' * 10)
            if computador == 2:
                if n == 1:
                    print('\033[32mComputador vence\033[m')
                    print('-=' * 10)
                    print('computador =', computador)
                    print('Jogador =', n)
                    print('-=' * 10)
                if n == 2:
                    print('\033[33mEMPATE\033[m')
                    print('-=' * 10)
                    print('computador =', computador)
                    print('Jogador =', n)
                    print('-=' * 10)
                if n == 3:
                    print('\033[34mJogador Vence!\033[m')
                    print('-=' * 10)
                    print('computador =', computador)
                    print('Jogador =', n)
                    print('-=' * 10)
                if n == 4:
                    print('\033[34mJogador Vence!\033[m')
                    print('-=' * 10)
                    print('computador =', computador)
                    print('Jogador =', n)
                    print('-=' * 10)
                if n == 5:
                    print('\033[32mComputador Vence!\033[m')
                    print('-=' * 10)
                    print('computador =', computador)
                    print('Jogador =', n)
                    print('-=' * 10)
            if computador == 3:
                if n == 1:
                    print('\033[34mJogador Vence!\033[m')
                    print('-=' * 10)
                    print('computador =', computador)
                    print('Jogador =', n)
                    print('-=' * 10)
                if n == 2:
                    print('\033[32mComputador Vence!\033[m')
                    print('-=' * 10)
                    print('computador =', computador)
                    print('Jogador =', n)
                    print('-=' * 10)
                if n == 3:
                    print('\033[33mEMPATE!\033[m')
                    print('-=' * 10)
                    print('computador =', computador)
                    print('Jogador =', n)
                    print('-=' * 10)
                if n == 4:
                    print('\033[32mComputador Vence!\033[m')
                    print('\033[34mJogador Vence!\033[m')
                    print('\033[34mJogador Vence!\033[m')
                    print('-=' * 10)
                    print('computador =', computador)
                    print('Jogador =', n)
                    print('-=' * 10)
                if n == 5:
                    print('\033[34mJogador Vence!\033[m')
                    print('-=' * 10)
                    print('computador =', computador)
                    print('Jogador =', n)
                    print('-=' * 10)
            if computador == 4:
                if n == 1:
                    print('\033[34mJogador Vence!\033[m')
                    print('-=' * 10)
                    print('computador =', computador)
                    print('Jogador =', n)
                    print('-=' * 10)
                if n == 2:
                    print('\033[32mComputador Vence!\033[m')
                    print('-=' * 10)
                    print('computador =', computador)
                    print('Jogador =', n)
                    print('-=' * 10)
                if n == 3:
                    print('\033[32mComputador Vence!\033[m')
                    print('-=' * 10)
                    print('computador =', computador)
                    print('Jogador =', n)
                    print('-=' * 10)
                if n == 4:
                    print('\033[33mEMPATE!\033[m')
                    print('-=' * 10)
                    print('computador =', computador)
                    print('Jogador =', n)
                    print('-=' * 10)
                if n == 5:
                    print('\033[32mCompuador Vence!\033[m')
                    print('-=' * 10)
                    print('computador =', computador)
                    print('Jogador =', n)
                    print('-=' * 10)
            if computador == 5:
                if n == 1:
                    print('\033[32mComputador Vence!\033[m')
                    print('-=' * 10)
                    print('computador =', computador)
                    print('Jogador =', n)
                    print('-=' * 10)
                if n == 2:
                    print('\033[32mComputador Vence!\033[m')
                    print('-=' * 10)
                    print('computador =', computador)
                    print('Jogador =', n)
                    print('-=' * 10)
                if n == 3:
                    print('\033[34mJogador Vence!\033[m')
                    print('-=' * 10)
                    print('computador =', computador)
                    print('Jogador =', n)
                    print('-=' * 10)
                if n == 4:
                    print('\033[34mJogador Vence!\033[m')
                    print('-=' * 10)
                    print('computador =', computador)
                    print('Jogador =', n)
                    print('-=' * 10)
                if n == 5:
                    print('\033[33mEMPATE!\033[m')
                    print('-=' * 10)
                    print('computador =', computador)
                    print('Jogador =', n)
                    print('-=' * 10)
```

Comment: Depende. O que seu código deveria fazer? E o que está fazendo? Aparece alguma mensagem de erro? Qual?

Comment: Se eu escolho a opção 1 o Jogador vai ganhar sempre, se eu escolho a op 2 o pc sempre ganha ,se eu escolho a op 3 sempre dá empate

Comment: Dica de ouro de quem é competidor de diversas olimpíadas de conhecimento: reduza seu problema. Você está tentando fazer um gerador de números aleatórios? Então não misture com a interface. Quer fazer o relacionamento entre pedra e tesoura? Ignore que há um computador e um jogador humano. Resolva e foque uma coisa de cada vez

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No inicio do programa é definido o valor de `computador = randint(1, 5)` , então o valor fica fixo não se alterando até que jogo seja reaberto.

```
print('\033[31m=\033[m'*30)
print('        \033[30mMENU DE JOGO\033[m')
print('\033[31m=\033[m'*30)
print('PEDRA, PAPEL, TESOURA, LAGARTO, SPOCK')
print('''opções:
[ 0 ] Regras
[ 7 ] Jogar
[ 6 ] Sair''')
n = int(input('Qual a sua opção:'))
while True:
    if n < 0 or n > 7:
        print('\033[31mOPÇÃO INVÁLIDA\033[m')
    elif n == 0:
        print('''Manual de como jogar pedra papel tesoura lagarto Spock:
Tesoura corta papel
papel cobre a pedra
pedra esmaga o lagarto 
Lagarto envenena Spock
Spock quebra a tesoura
tesoura decapita o lagarto
lagarto come o papel
papel refuta Spock
Spock vaporiza a pedra
pedra esmaga a tesoura'''.upper())
        print('PEDRA, PAPEL, TESOURA, LAGARTO, SPOCK')
        print('''opções:
        [ 0 ] Regras
        [ 7 ] Jogar
        [ 6 ] Sair''')
        n = int(input('Qual a sua opção:'))
    if n == 0:
            print('''
Manual de como jogar pedra papel tesoura lagarto Spock:
Tesoura corta papel
papel cobre a pedra
pedra esmaga o lagarto 
Lagarto envenena Spock
Spock quebra a tesoura
tesoura decapita o lagarto
lagarto come o papel
papel refuta Spock
Spock vaporiza a pedra
pedra esmaga a tesoura'''.upper())
    if n == 6:
        break
    if n > 7 or n < 0:
        print('\033[31mOPÇÃO INVÁLIDA\033[m')
        n = int(input('Qual a sua opção:'))
    if n == 7:
        while True:
            print('''
[ 1 ] Pedra
[ 2 ] Papel
[ 3 ] Tesoura
[ 4 ] Lagarto
[ 5 ] Spock
[ 6 ] Voltar''')
            n = int(input('Qual a sua opção:'))
            if n == 6:
                print('\033[31m=\033[m' * 30)
                print('        \033[30mMENU DE JOGO\033[m')
                print('\033[31m=\033[m' * 30)
                print('''
PEDRA, PAPEL, TESOURA, LAGARTO, SPOCK''')
                print('''
opções:
[ 0 ] Regras
[ 7 ] Jogar
[ 6 ] Sair''')
                n = int(input('Qual a sua opção:'))
                if n == 6:
                    break
                if n > 7 or n < 0:
                    print('\033[31mOPÇÃO INVÁLIDA\033[m')
            computador = randint(1, 5)
            if computador == 1:
                if n == 1:
                    print('\033[33mEMPATE\033[m')
                    print('-=' * 10)
                    print('computador =', computador)
                    print('Jogador =', n)
                    print('-=' * 10)
                if n == 2:
                    print('\033[34mJogador Vence!\033[m')
                    print('-=' * 10)
                    print('computador =', computador)
                    print('Jogador =', n)
                    print('-=' * 10)
                if n == 3:
                    print('\033[32mComputador Vence!\033[m')
                    print('-=' * 10)
                    print('computador =', computador)
                    print('Jogador =', n)
                    print('-=' * 10)
                if n == 4:
                    print('\033[32mComputador Vence!\033[m')
                    print('-=' * 10)
                    print('computador =', computador)
                    print('Jogador =', n)
                    print('-=' * 10)
                if n == 5:
                    print('\033[34mJogador Vence!\033[m')
                    print('-=' * 10)
                    print('computador =', computador)
                    print('Jogador =', n)
                    print('-=' * 10)
            if computador == 2:
                if n == 1:
                    print('\033[32mComputador vence\033[m')
                    print('-=' * 10)
                    print('computador =', computador)
                    print('Jogador =', n)
                    print('-=' * 10)
                if n == 2:
                    print('\033[33mEMPATE\033[m')
                    print('-=' * 10)
                    print('computador =', computador)
                    print('Jogador =', n)
                    print('-=' * 10)
                if n == 3:
                    print('\033[34mJogador Vence!\033[m')
                    print('-=' * 10)
                    print('computador =', computador)
                    print('Jogador =', n)
                    print('-=' * 10)
                if n == 4:
                    print('\033[34mJogador Vence!\033[m')
                    print('-=' * 10)
                    print('computador =', computador)
                    print('Jogador =', n)
                    print('-=' * 10)
                if n == 5:
                    print('\033[32mComputador Vence!\033[m')
                    print('-=' * 10)
                    print('computador =', computador)
                    print('Jogador =', n)
                    print('-=' * 10)
            if computador == 3:
                if n == 1:
                    print('\033[34mJogador Vence!\033[m')
                    print('-=' * 10)
                    print('computador =', computador)
                    print('Jogador =', n)
                    print('-=' * 10)
                if n == 2:
                    print('\033[32mComputador Vence!\033[m')
                    print('-=' * 10)
                    print('computador =', computador)
                    print('Jogador =', n)
                    print('-=' * 10)
                if n == 3:
                    print('\033[33mEMPATE!\033[m')
                    print('-=' * 10)
                    print('computador =', computador)
                    print('Jogador =', n)
                    print('-=' * 10)
                if n == 4:
                    print('\033[32mComputador Vence!\033[m')
                    print('\033[34mJogador Vence!\033[m')
                    print('-=' * 10)
                    print('computador =', computador)
                    print('Jogador =', n)
                    print('-=' * 10)
                if n == 5:
                    print('\033[34mJogador Vence!\033[m')
                    print('-=' * 10)
                    print('computador =', computador)
                    print('Jogador =', n)
                    print('-=' * 10)
            if computador == 4:
                if n == 1:
                    print('\033[34mJogador Vence!\033[m')
                    print('-=' * 10)
                    print('computador =', computador)
                    print('Jogador =', n)
                    print('-=' * 10)
                if n == 2:
                    print('\033[32mComputador Vence!\033[m')
                    print('-=' * 10)
                    print('computador =', computador)
                    print('Jogador =', n)
                    print('-=' * 10)
                if n == 3:
                    print('\033[32mComputador Vence!\033[m')
                    print('-=' * 10)
                    print('computador =', computador)
                    print('Jogador =', n)
                    print('-=' * 10)
                if n == 4:
                    print('\033[33mEMPATE!\033[m')
                    print('-=' * 10)
                    print('computador =', computador)
                    print('Jogador =', n)
                    print('-=' * 10)
                if n == 5:
                    print('\033[32mCompuador Vence!\033[m')
                    print('-=' * 10)
                    print('computador =', computador)
                    print('Jogador =', n)
                    print('-=' * 10)
            if computador == 5:
                if n == 1:
                    print('\033[32mComputador Vence!\033[m')
                    print('-=' * 10)
                    print('computador =', computador)
                    print('Jogador =', n)
                    print('-=' * 10)
                if n == 2:
                    print('\033[32mComputador Vence!\033[m')
                    print('-=' * 10)
                    print('computador =', computador)
                    print('Jogador =', n)
                    print('-=' * 10)
                if n == 3:
                    print('\033[34mJogador Vence!\033[m')
                    print('-=' * 10)
                    print('computador =', computador)
                    print('Jogador =', n)
                    print('-=' * 10)
                if n == 4:
                    print('\033[34mJogador Vence!\033[m')
                    print('-=' * 10)
                    print('computador =', computador)
                    print('Jogador =', n)
                    print('-=' * 10)
                if n == 5:
                    print('\033[33mEMPATE!\033[m')
                    print('-=' * 10)
                    print('computador =', computador)
                    print('Jogador =', n)
                    print('-=' * 10)
```